# Multivariate Function Approximation With a Large Dataset

Tags: function-construction, fitting, approximation

I have a nice amount of data from a trading strategy I am working on, where I have two different liquidity parameters as x, y variables.

Before entering a trade I am taking the moving average of `Volume*SharePrice & if > than my "liquidity requirement"` I enter, along with other unmentioned rules. The length of the moving average is my x variable and my liquidity requirement is my y variable. My data includes several outputs over these x and y variables such as P/L, ROI, $Won, etc.

My question is: how can I use Mathematica to interpolate an approximate function for any output so that I can optimize x, y? For instance say I want to approximate ROI=f(x,y) or P/L=f(x,y)...I dont expect something that describes my data perfectly, but something that approximates it would greatly help.

Comment: type `?*Interpolation*` browse the corresponding documentation  (which can be evaluated), write a similar code, improve it, and if it works I ll only take 30 % of the net profit for this great advice ;-)

Comment: Yeah I saw that documentation and I was doing something wrong before, but now I seem to have it working. Can I use the Interpolating function as a regular function? For instance say I have f1=Interpolation[DollarWon] and f2=Interpolation[DollarLost] can I now do Maximize[f1-f2,{x,y}]?

Comment: you can do `dat = Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8.}];
f1 = Interpolation[dat];
NMinimize[{f1[x], x > 0, x < 2 Pi}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I am still getting hung up on the NMaximize.. I have `PL = data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]];` where data is a csv holding all my backtest results. I am able to successfully get the Interpolation with `f1 = Interpolation[PL];` But trying `NMaximize[{f1[x, y], x >= 30, x <= 90, y >= 1000000, 
  y <= 10000000}, {x, y}]` yields **NMinimize::nnum: The function value InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,6.28319}},<<3>>,{Automatic}][89.9186,1.83176*10^6] is not a number at {x,y} = {89.9186,1.83176*10^6}. >>**

Comment: I am confused by this bit **{x, 0, 2 Pi}** in your NMinimize.. isnt this supposed to be the choice variables mathematica searches for? I am having trouble finding documentation on this function regarding multivariate functions... I hope I am not driving you crazy, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: have you looked at your data within mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

Let's just consider a test case:

```
dat = Table[{x, y, -Sin[x]*Sin[y]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/8.}, {y, 0, Pi, Pi/8}];

f = Interpolation[Flatten[dat, 1]];
```

as a check let us plot sections through the interpolation.

```
Plot[Table[f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi, Pi/8}]//Evaluate, {y, 0, Pi}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let's minimize that interpolated function:

```
NMinimize[{f[x, y], x > 0, x <= Pi, y >= 0, y <= Pi}, {{x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}}]

(* ==> {-1., {x -> 1.5708, y -> 1.5708}} *)
```

Comment: Awesome! This got me where I needed to be! I really appreciate the write up!